# Detect if Night Shift mode is active on iOS

Tags: ios, ios9.3

I have looked a bit in the [iOS 9.3 API Diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS93APIDiffs/index.html), as well as searching the developer website and forums and did not see any references.

Is it possible to determine if Night Shift is active? I would assume that applications which require true color tone would want to alert a user if the screen colors were being augmented by the system.

Comment: I imagined this would be in UIScreen with the brightness settings but it doesn't look like it's there.  Interesting, I'll keep digging.

Comment: I've made some progress on this.  There appears to be a new class in the private CoreBrightness framework called [`NightModeControl`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/CoreBrightness.framework/NightModeControl.h) which controls Night Shift.  I haven't found a way to hook into any of the CoreBrightness classes at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not provide an API for accessing the users Night Shift setting.

Comment: Could you provide a reference, please?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe if Apple doesn't provide it, what reference are we looking for?